Getting bitnami openLDAP working with memberOf and ldif user config
i'm trying to configure the bitnami ldap server (docker) with the memberOf functionality. I have mounted the schemas dir (with the overlay ldif) and ldif dir for users and groups.
Here is my overlay:
# Load modules
dn: cn=module,cn=config
cn: module
objectClass: olcModuleList
olcModuleLoad: memberof
olcmoduleload: refint
olcModulePath: /opt/bitnami/openldap/lib/openldap

#memberof overlay
dn: olcOverlay=memberof,olcDatabase={2}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcMemberOf
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcConfig
objectClass: top
olcOverlay: memberof
olcMemberOfDangling: ignore
olcMemberOfRefInt: TRUE
olcMemberOfGroupOC: groupOfNames
olcMemberOfMemberAD: member
olcMemberOfMemberOfAD: memberOf

#refint overlay
dn: olcOverlay=refint,olcDatabase={2}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcRefintConfig
olcOverlay: refint
olcRefintAttribute: owner
olcRefintAttribute: manager
olcRefintAttribute: member
olcRefintAttribute: memberOf

and here the user and groups:
dn: dc=maxcrc,dc=com
changetype: add
objectClass: domain
objectClass: top
dc: maxcrc

dn: ou=People,dc=maxcrc,dc=com
changetype: add
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: People
description: Container for user entries

dn: ou=Groups,dc=maxcrc,dc=com
changetype: add
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: Groups
description: Container for group entries

dn: cn=admingroup,ou=Groups,dc=maxcrc,dc=com
changetype: add
objectClass: groupOfNames
cn: admingroup
member: cn=Jack Miller,ou=People,dc=maxcrc,dc=com

dn: cn=Jack Miller,ou=People,dc=maxcrc,dc=com
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
cn: Jack Miller
sn: miller
userPassword: 1234

If i try to add the "memberOf: cn=admingroup,ou=Groups,dc=maxcrc,dc=com" to the user miller, the server won't start. Maybe there is an example ldif that should work?
I tried web examples, already read the stackoverflow questions/answers, but nothing helped. In debug mode there is this error (32 - wrong dn???):

memberof_value_modify DN="cn=jack miller,ou=people,dc=maxcrc,dc=com"
add memberOf="cn=admingroup,ou=Groups,dc=maxcrc,dc=com" failed err=32

